# Font Awesome icon not displaying in Apple System

Tags: font-awesome, opencart2.x

Font Awesome icons not show in Apple Computer browser with OpenCart 2. It is working fine in window system.

Website - http://www.expresscost.com/

what is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: It happens sometimes, you can try importing font awesome css from CDN //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: What is the font-family applied on Mac ?